# Combine 2 datasources into 1 tableview

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

I'm need some advice, i'm needing to combine 2 datasources into 1 tableview.

Currently i have just 1 table view, and the data is being fed from an SQLite database, my plan would be to have 2 sections, the 1st providing data from 1 database, and the second section providing data from a second database.... Any ideas how i'd go about it?

Answer (score 1):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can use the indexPath.section to differentiate each section for a row.